# Blazor server side Cookie Authentication - direct link work even user is not authenticated

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm follow this [tutorial](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36) for simple cookie auth in Blazor server side.

for the most part i got it working but user can still access the page mark with

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "User, Admin")]
```

via direct link.

the navi link that I have on the menu marked with  will not show unless user login. so i believe it work.

the first comment in the tutorial said change:

```
<routeview routedata="@routeData" defaultlayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
```

to

```
<authorizerouteview routedata="@routeData" defaultlayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
```

and the whole site is blank

Comment: Can you post more details about your pages? Do you use `<AuthorizeView>` there? I would advise you to go over the official Microsoft documentation here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0. You can also create a blank project with Authentication and see how thinks work there. Be advises that the authentication does not work via SignalR and HTTP requests are required in order to refresh / set the authentication cookies

Comment: yes, i use AuthorizeView

Comment: The tutorial you have referenced has a clear message at the top - ** Notice: This article is outdated (see changes in the comments or use another guide) **.  Pick a more modern guide - you haven't given any details on what you mean by "Simple" so it's difficult to point you to one that fits your needs!